# Image search on an offline website

Tags: c#, search

What is the best way to search an offline website in C#. I would like to do an image search of a site saved locally, returning images from pages that contain particular search terms.

Is there a library or tool that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can parse the HTML using `RegEx`?

Comment: Your post will probably be deleted because it doesn't meet the criteria for questions.   Try HTML Agility Pack:  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/